# react-native-material-ui@1.12.0 requires a peer of react-native-vector- icons@^4.0.0 but none was installed

Tags: react-native, dependencies

hello everyone i am new to react native and started learning the react from last week.

But now i stuck on problem that react-native-vector-icons doesn't install properly,i don't know why its happen.i am not getting what is the exact issue

here is my package.json

```
  {
"name": "ephotobook",
"version": "0.0.1",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
"start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
"test": "jest"
},
"dependencies": {
"react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
"react-native": "0.46.3",
"react-native-icons": "^0.7.1",
"react-native-material-ui": "^1.12.0"

},
"devDependencies": {
"babel-jest": "20.0.3",
"babel-preset-react-native": "2.1.0",
"jest": "20.0.4",
"react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
 },
"jest": {
"preset": "react-native"
}
 }
```

when  i run npm install react-native-vector-icons
i get the following error

```
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react-native-vector-icons@^4.0.0

 npm WARN react-native-material-ui@1.12.0 requires a peer of react-native-vector-
 icons@^4.0.0 but none was installed.
```

please help me to install both material ui and vecctor icons

Comment: add `"react-native-vector-icons": "^4.0.0",` before material ui in dependencies

Comment: Thanks solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in warning you need to add vector icons to package.json before installing material ui.

`"react-native-vector-icons": "^4.0.0"`

Comment: You can mark as accepted answer if you found useful and close the question as problem was resolved

Answer (score 0):

You can update version of react-native-vector-icon in your package.json like :

```
"react-native-vector-icons": "^4.0.0",
```

I hope this is can help you.